# Received(queue) or Executing multiple tasks at same time in celery

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I added 10 tasks in celery process. It picks one by one (default celery process). After the completion of first task it picks the second task received and executed .

Those tasks are not depending on each other. so I want to run simultaneously or I want to received all the 10 tasks in queue(celery console) and executing one by one.

```
 -------------- celery@rana-04 v5.1.2 (sun-harmonics)
 --- ***** -----
 -- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0 2021-08-16 13:18:28
 - *** --- * ---  
 - ** ---------- [config]
 - ** ---------- .> app:         rana:0x2507baac198
 - ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
 - ** ---------- .> results:
 - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (solo)
 -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
 --- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
            .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

Celery Command :

```
celery -A rana worker --loglevel=INFO --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat -Ofair --pool=solo
```

Any command changes or configurations needed ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue? @Rana

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use --pool=solo in your command. Because the pool of worker just can hold one task at the same time.